# How to add role based authorization to my Spring boot application using REST?

Tags: javascript, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to build an application with the following requirements:

- Use spring framework with hibernate on the back end and HTML,CSS,JS on the front end.
- Access to the application needs to be done using a REST.
- Content on the application will be displayed according to roles of the user.
- Users may raise a request on the portal which needs to go through several levels of approval and at each approval level some data is added to the request form.
- The back end and front end are going to be totally separate communication will be using ajax calls and data is going to be passed in JSON.

Need help about how to keep user data(username, role) captured at all times and how to go about building this application.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question ? Spring security will hold the user info and access role of the user accessing the application.

Comment: I'm looking for an example of sorts to implement authentication using JWT.